# Error C2664: cannot convert argument 1 from 'imaging::component_t *' to 'const imaging::component_t *&'

Tags: c++, c2664

I have the error I mentioned in the title on this part of my code.

```
component_t *buffer = new component_t[3 * width*height];
component_t getRawDataPtr();

...
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width*height * 3; i = i + 3) {
        file.read((char *)cR, sizeof(char));
        file.read((char *)cG, sizeof(char));
        file.read((char *)cB, sizeof(char));
        buffer[i] = cR / 255.0f;
        buffer[i + 1] = cG / 255.0f;
        buffer[i + 2] = cB / 255.0f;
    }
    file.close();

    image->setData(buffer);

...

void Image::setData(const component_t * & data_ptr) {
    if (height == 0 || width == 0 || buffer == nullptr)
        return;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < height*width * 3; i++)
        buffer[i] = data_ptr[i];
}
```

I tried image->setData(*buffer) or image->setData(&buffer) but that didn't work either. If anyone knows how to fix this I'd appreciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to pass a const reference to the pointer, the format it `component_t* const&`. Not that passing by reference is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change:

```
void Image::setData(const component_t * & data_ptr) {
```

to:

```
void Image::setData(const component_t * data_ptr) {
```

or:

```
image->setData(buffer);
```

to

```
const component_t *cbuffer = buffer;
image->setData(cbuffer);
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was exactly what i wanted :D

Answer (score 0):

You try to assign a const pointer to a non-const pointer

```
buffer[i] = data_ptr[i];
```

This is not allowed, because this would violate the const promise on `data_ptr`.